# How to run unit tests for Xamarin library projects (iOS and Android)?

Tags: android, ios, nunit, xamarin, library-project

I'm creating a component for the Xamarin Component Store, providing a Library for Android and iOS. I've put NUnit tests into both library projects but I can't run the unit tests. Is it possible to execute tests in a Android/iOS library project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you make your library a PCL, you can create a NUnit project that links to the PCL and run your tests that way:
https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/0H3W383D2e031q1p3s40/Screen%20Shot%202013-08-12%20at%207.56.05%20PM.png?v=d5aac873

Xamarin also provides a NUnitLite test runner for iOS:
http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/touch.unit

With the latest version of Xamarin Studio you can also create an Android Unit Test project:
https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/3v3x192S473g182C2S2a/Screen%20Shot%202013-08-12%20at%207.55.41%20PM.png?v=f0dce0f9

Comment: but it is not in the Visual Studio for 4.12.1

Comment: Is there a way to run these tests from ReSharper's test explorer? It seems like it doesn't recognize such tests...