# Unittest for a PCL - LINQ method fails

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin

We like to use TTD and with Xamarin we use NUnit for that. In our project we have a PCL and a monodroid/montouch project. We have also iOS and Android integrationtest-projects (with NUnit but with the special testrunner).

My problem is that real unittests (the fast ones executed NOT in the simulator) we use for TTD don't work with the PCL (and there it's most important) as soon as we use LINQ-extension-methods like for example

```
Enumerable.Any()
```

The exception we get is always:

```
could not load file or assembly system.core 2.0.5.0
```

If we don't use linq methods, everything works fine... Maybe as info: in the integrationtest-projects we can execute this tests without problem, with our without LINQ extensions.

The PCL looks like that:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
<OutputType>Library</OutputType>
<RootNamespace>XYLib</RootNamespace>
<AssemblyName>XYLib</AssemblyName>
<TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile136</TargetFrameworkProfile>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

And the unittest-project is a Xamarin-Studio "NUnit Library Project" (we also tried a lot of other project-types without success).

I spent a lot of time for googling this problem. According to this post, it should work this way: [How to run unit tests for Xamarin library projects (iOS and Android)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175191/how-to-run-unit-tests-for-xamarin-library-projects-ios-and-android)

Can anybody help me with this? Or is it not possible?

Comment: Many things are unclear... TTD? you mean "Test Driven Development (TDD)" ? *with the special testrunner* do you mean Touch.Unit (shipped with XI and runs the tests in the simulator or devices) ? It seems not since *the fast ones executed NOT in the simulator* (so which is your execution environment ?). In any case if your project reference (directly or not) `monotouch.dll` then it will need to be run inside the simulator (or devices).

Comment: Thx for asking, poupou. Your assumptions are all correct, I mean Test Driven Development, where the tests often target only a single class (or component) and need to run inside the IDE without simulating a device. We also use the testrunner for our integrationtests, but they are platform-dependent and need to start an iOS/android simulator. We just want to have simple unit tests for our PCL code, platform-independent and very fast (executed by the IDE).

Comment: I don't see that we use the monotouch.dll, would that be even possible in a PCL? Here a screenshot of all the references we have in the PCL: https://db.tt/Yv5oky0g. Some of them are included with conditions (for example Restharp)

Answer (score 0):

Do the unit tests fail when you use LINQ extensions in the unit test code or in the PCL code that's being called by the unit tests?

If you're returning a deferred LINQ query from the PCL and then applying a LINQ extension from what could effectively be a different version of LINQ, I could see where there might be trouble. In which case, try using .ToList() to force the query to execute before you apply your unit test-specific LINQ code.

Comment: Hey Steve, LINQ extensions are not used in the test code, but in the effective code, called by the test methods.
Since I wrote this issue, we changed our project setup a lot. For the mentioned project we use now a Shared Project instead of a PCL (mainly because of the huge amount of third party libraries it relies on). With this setup we can use unit tests without problems.